# How to create the Horizontal ScrollBar at the bottom of DataGrid as in GWT CellSampler example?

Tags: gwt, gwtp, gwt-platform

I like `DataGrid` since it has fixed header so wen user scrolldown they are still be able to see the column header.

However, if there are too many columns then the `DataGrid` will manage to fit all columns within the Fixed Width of the widget that contain it.

For example, if a 30 column `DataGrid` was put inside a center (with 100px) of a `DockLayoutPanel` then all 30 columns will be divided evenly within 100px, which is make it unreadable cos the with of each column is too small.

So, I would love to use `DataGrid` but the `DataGrid` should have a Horizontal ScrollBar at the bottom so if there are many column then the user can just scroll horizontally to the right to see the data.

If we do correctly, then it should be like the **GWT CellSampler example** http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellSampler

Clearly, the CellSampler used `DataGid`, but I didn't see any Horizontal ScrollBar code in there.

So how to make DataGrid to display as in the CellSampler example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set the minimum width for your DataGrid:

```
myDataGrid.setMinimumTableWidth(600, Unit.PX);
```

Comment: Thax u very much Andrei, great but 1 minor thing. Can we make it dynamically? or is there anyway to make it dynamically?

Comment: is it ok if i do like this "dbGrid.setMinimumTableWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Unit.PX);", will it create any issue?

Comment: or we can calculate size of each column and cal the total size of all columns?

Comment: also myDataGrid.setMinimumTableWidth(600, Unit.PX); does not work in IE6 and earlier version

Comment: You can set the width at any time.

Comment: Thax you very much, your answer met the requirement, but I got other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24817498/how-to-calculate-column-width-that-fits-cell-width-to-its-content-in-gwt

Answer (score 0):

I have done following for My Table Datagrid.

```
     FlowPanel tablePanel = new FlowPanel();
    tablePanel.add( table );
    tablePanel.getElement().setAttribute( "style",
        "overflow-x: auto;width: " + ( Window.getClientWidth() - 37 ) + "px;clear: both" );
    add( tablePanel );
```